# How to attach Link

Tags: discussion

I had seen using people link in their answers.Please let me know how to do that so can I answer in an effective way.A snapshot is added to explain which type of linking I am talking about.[image]

Actually the way "Announcer,Booster"have been linked I want to learn.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: @muru In the website provided by you it is given that"you can use the visual editor (for questions and answers, but not comments)"So,Can I know how you did it in your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Link markdown is as follows:

```
[text](url)
```

So the following markdown:

```
[test](http://example.org)
```

Produces the following output when rendered:

> [test](http://example.org)